# Show that a finite-dimensional Banach space has a bijective compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, compact-operators

It is clear that if $ T: X \rightarrow X $ is a bijective compact operator, where $ X $ is a Banach space, then $ \dim(\text{Range}(T)) = \dim(X) $, which implies that $ \dim(X) $ must be $ < \infty $.

How do I prove the converse: If $ \dim(X) < \infty $, then there exists a bijective compact operator $ T: X \rightarrow X $?

Thank you!

Comment: There's some sort of typo in the first sentence of your question.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong : i think now its correct .

Comment: The first statement, namely proving that the existence of a bijective compact operator $ T: X \rightarrow X $ implies that $ \dim(X) < \infty $, is actually a non-trivial result. It is a more difficult problem than the one that the OP is posing. Every operator on a finite-dimensional Banach space is compact. Hence, the identity operator on a finite-dimensional Banach space is a bijective compact operator.

Comment: In fact, a finite-dimensional Banach space $ X $ is nothing other than a finite-dimensional Euclidean space. This follows from the fact that all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space (over $ \mathbb{R} $ or $ \mathbb{C} $) are equivalent. Hence, every bijective operator on $ X $ can be represented as an invertible matrix with respect to a fixed finite basis of $ X $. As such, there are $ 2^{\aleph_{0}} $-many bijective compact operators on a finite-dimensional Banach space, with the identity operator being one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose the theorem you want to prove is this one:

> Let $(X,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ be a Banach space. There exists a linear continuous operator $T \colon X \to X$ compact if and only if $\dim X <+\infty$.

One way (*if*) is clear: indeed, if $\dim X<+\infty$ then *every* operator $T \colon X \to X$ is compact (since its range is finite dimensional: this is a well-known sufficient condition for compactness). For example, take identity of $X$: it is bijective (obviously!) and compact.

Now, the other way (*only if*): suppose $T\colon X \to X$ is bijective and compact. There exists $T^{-1}$ and, moreover, it is continuous: so $TT^{-1}=\text{id}_X$ is compact, since $\mathcal K(X)$ is a closed ideal in $\mathcal L(X)$. In particular, the closure of the unit ball of $X$ is compact, hence the space $X$ is finite dimensional.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if $T$ is compact then is it required that rank of $T$ is always finite dimensional ?

Comment: No. The implication you ask for should be the easy one.

Comment: I perfectly agree with you, jiku1797. Anyway, I've added some details.

Comment: @Romeo: My comment was meant to answer Theorem's misunderstanding regarding compact operators. Your comment is completely fine!

Comment: @Romeo : Thanks!

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Romeo But in your statement you don't mention that $T$ should be bijective. Does the proof still hold if it is not?

Comment: @Romeo your statement is wrong!! You need either $T$ bijective of $Im(T)$ closed subspace

Answer (score 5):

Theorem, it is not true that $ \dim(\text{Range}(T)) = \dim(X) $ implies that $ \dim(X) < \infty $. Another way of reasoning is as follows. Let $ T: X \rightarrow X $ be a bijective compact operator. Then by the Bounded Inverse Theorem, $ T^{-1} $ exists and is continuous. Hence, $ T $ is also a homeomorphism. Let $ B_{X} $ be the closed unit ball of $ X $. Then $ T[B_{X}] $ is closed and has compact closure, which implies that $ T[B_{X}] $ is compact (a closed subset of a compact space is also compact). However, as $ T $ is a homeomorphism, $ B_{X} $ must then be compact. Hence, as a consequence of Riesz's Lemma, $ \dim(X) < \infty $.

Of course, Romeo's answer is very slick in the sense that reasoning with the ideal $ \mathcal{K}(X) $ saves us a lot of work.